# Bose-Einstein Distribution function

Tags: quantum-mechanics, statistical-mechanics

Why is the following equation :

$\bar n_\epsilon=\frac 1 {e^{\beta (\epsilon_p - \mu) } \pm 1}$

called a distribution function?

In wikipedia the definition of a distribution function (a.k.a Cumulative distribution function) is:

A function that has values from 0 to 1. Here we can have values greater the 1. So how is the above equation a distribution function (of a continues variable).

Answer (score 0):

It's not a probability distribution function. The distribution function in the sense that it tells us the distribution of particles among various energy levels. It's by definition is the mean occupation of a state with energy $E$ so
$$\langle n\rangle =f(E)=\frac{1}{e^{\beta(E-\mu)}\pm 1}$$